# How to sort by sum(:field) without using temp filesort

Tags: mysql

So we want to have the objects who received the most points by user actions (comments, image uploads etc). each action is stored with its points-value and the target.

```
select sum(points) as points, target_type,target_id from user_actions where target_type="Modification" group by target_id order by points DESC limit 100
```

**Showing rows 0 - 99 (100 total, Query took 200.7865 seconds.)**

**Table size 4M rows.**

Index on **target_type**, **target_id**.

If i EXPLAIN the query, it says it is using temporary filesort. that obviously is killing it.

**question**

do i have any chances of speeding this query up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another index or changing the existing one if it's not used in another place .

`Points` column is not indexed, if it will be it should improve your performance significantly :

```
CREATE INDEX user_actions_indx 
ON user_actions (target_type,target_id,points);
```

Comment: i can index a field which is non existent? because i use SUM(points)

Comment: Well, not exactly, but the calculation of this column will take seconds. Try adding it and tell me how much it improved your query @huanson

Comment: 175.7720 seconds. not sure if we can call that improvement.
But what i can call "fail" is the fact, that everybody now got -17 points :D i think the index is not a good idea.

Comment: sorry. seems my indexes werent really indexed. i optimized table. now it's about 12seconds. that's "ok"

Comment: Told you that should improve it significantly, and an index can't change results, so I don't know what happen. @huanson I'll appreciate an approval then:)